# Raw Sub Query inside selectRaw

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

```
 BowlerMaster::selectRaw(" 
    tour_id, bowler_id, bowler_name, ball_team,
    SUM(balls) AS balls,
    SUM(overs) AS overs,                
    DB::raw('SELECT runs, wicket FROM bowler_master WHERE tour_id = ".$request->tour_id." AND bowler_id = ".$request->player_id." ORDER BY wicket DESC, runs LIMIT 1 AS bbi')
        ")
->where($where_array)
->groupby(['tour_id','bowler_id'])
->get()->first();
```

In the above Eloquent Query I want to use raw query or any other wayout for getting the result of the raw query to get the value of bbi, but I am getting the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '::raw('SELECT match_id, runs, wicket FROM bowler_master WHERE tour_id = 1 AND bo' at line 25.

I am writing writing this query for generating following output,

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "bowler": {
        "tour_id": 1,
        "bowler_id": 21,
        "bowler_name": "Kaushal Chauhan",
        "ball_team": null,
        "balls": "29",
        "overs": 4.5,
        "bbi": 9/3,
    }
}
```

Uptil overs calculation, everything is working fine. I am not getting how to get the "bbi" key:value
Note: The result of the query will be pushed in response array and will be converted into json to get the output shown above.

Please guide.

Comment: Show your table structure and expected result.

Comment: I have edited the question with table structure and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
BowlerMaster::selectRaw("tour_id, bowler_id, bowler_name, ball_team, SUM(balls) AS balls,SUM(overs) AS overs")
        ->selectSub("  
                   SELECT runs 
                   FROM bowler_master 
                   WHERE tour_id = ".$request->tour_id." 
                   AND bowler_id = ".$request->player_id." 
                   ORDER BY wicket DESC, runs LIMIT 1
        ","runs")
        ->selectSub("  
                    SELECT wicket 
                    FROM bowler_master 
                    WHERE tour_id = ".$request->tour_id." 
                    AND bowler_id = ".$request->player_id." 
                    ORDER BY wicket DESC, runs LIMIT 1
           ","wicket")
        ->where($where_array)
        ->groupby(['tour_id','bowler_id'])
        ->get()->first();
```

The rules of writing select sub query in laravel is as follows:

```
DB::table('tablename')
    ->select('column name','..')
    ->selectSub("Your full query","alias name")
    ->get()
```